# Swift MainActor not enforced on subclasses

Tags: ios, swift

I tried looking for documentation about this but I can't find any.

As far as I know, if you declare your superclass as `@MainActor`, any subclass will also be considered as `@MainActor`. However it seems that in practice this is not the case.

Take a `UIViewController` as example. This is declared as `@MainActor`, however:

```
import UIKit

class VC: UIViewController {
    
    func doSomething() {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            self.doSomethingElse()
        }
    }
    
    func doSomethingElse() {
        
        print("is main thread? \(Thread.isMainThread)")
    }
}

let vc = VC()

vc.doSomething()
```

This code will compile without errors and print `is main thread? false`

This code:

```
import UIKit

@MainActor
class VC: UIViewController {
    
    func doSomething() {
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            self.doSomethingElse()
        }
    }
    
    func doSomethingElse() {
        
        print("is main thread? \(Thread.isMainThread)")
    }
}

let vc = VC()

vc.doSomething()
```

Will not compile, it will show:

```
error: MyPlayground.playground:20:4: error: call to main actor-isolated instance method 'doSomething()' in a synchronous nonisolated context
vc.doSomething()
   ^

MyPlayground.playground:6:10: note: calls to instance method 'doSomething()' from outside of its actor context are implicitly asynchronous
    func doSomething() {
         ^

error: MyPlayground.playground:8:18: error: call to main actor-isolated instance method 'doSomethingElse()' in a synchronous nonisolated context
            self.doSomethingElse()
                 ^

MyPlayground.playground:12:10: note: calls to instance method 'doSomethingElse()' from outside of its actor context are implicitly asynchronous
    func doSomethingElse() {
         ^
```

Isn't the behaviour of the compiler in both cases supposed to be the same?

Comment: Yes it should. But it doesn't. I have filed this as a bug, in fact. See https://bugs.swift.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/SR-15131

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, this is a bug. [SR-15131](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-15131?jql=text%20%7E%20%22global%20actor%22) was resolved pretty recently so a fix should be coming in Swift 5.6.